# Each time i uninstall my flutter app manually and run it again it stuck in "Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk"

Tags: android, flutter, apk, flutter-getx

I'm using flutter with GetX in VScode and once it got stuck in "Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk" step for too long then I used `adb uninstall com.example.application.name` to uninstall it, after that each time I uninstall it manually from my device and run `flutter run` it dose the same thing and hang in the installing step forever.

so each time I need to uninstall the app I have to use the command `adb uninstall`

can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to solve it? and if I uploaded it on play store will this happen when the user uninstall it?

and why dose it even need me to use `adb uninstall` put the manual uninstallation isn't working?

Comment: Try to run `flutter doctor` et `flutter devices` to make sure everything is ok. You can also check for any error, maybe you're unable to install because the build number is lower that the one already installed (odd but maybe..)

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using wireless debugging so it's take time to run application.
- You can use USB debugging that runs faster than wireless debugging
  And also increase maximum logger size in developer option
- try to run `flutter clean` command than after run `flutter run` commend